# How is a model creator called?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

The title is not very informative, so i explain it here:

In my application I have a few classes, that provides methods to manage my data: for example, I delete a database entry, but after deleting it, I have to delete a file in another place. And because I need this method at multiple places in my application, I created a class for all those methods. On the other hand, I have many functions, that just gets some data from the database, processes them a little bit and returns them in a simple model.

But: how do I call such a class? I can't find any corresponding design pattern on wikipedia.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Unfortunately it's still pretty unclear what you're asking. We don't have any code snippets to get any context, nor do we understand how you're using the *classes you do have* today.

Comment: It's because your are not using a pattern. If you want, you can use the Command Pattern, but I believe that it's not what you want. You can create a class "Utils" and put your methods in there. So, instead of create a new instance all the time, you can use it as singleton.

Comment: The class with methods to communicate with the database could be called a `Repository`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to keeping your methods and functions nicely organised, I suggest you look at the [Command Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) (also http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternCommand.aspx)

The idea is to wrap your methods into command objects e.g. `DeleteDatabaseEntryCommand`, `DeleteFileCommand`, `LoadRecordsFromDatabaseCommand`. So you don't bother having one uber class that has these methods, you simply create an instance of the command you wish to execute.

I've used this pattern in the past and have found it very flexible. I also used a Factory design pattern with Command design pattern, like so:

```
public interface ICommand
{
    void Execute();
}

public class CreateUserCommand : ICommand
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}

public class DeleteUserCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly int _userId;

    public DeleteUserCommand(int userId)
    {
        _userId = userId;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Deleting " + _userId);
    }
}

public interface ICommandFactory
{
    ICommand Create<T>();
}

public class CommandFactory : ICommandFactory
{
    public ICommand Create<T>()
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance<T>() as ICommand;
    }

    public ICommand Create<T>(object[] args)
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), args) as ICommand;
    }
}
```

Example usage

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var factory = new CommandFactory();

        var cmd = factory.Create<DeleteUserCommand>(new object[] { 23 });

        cmd.Execute();
    }
}
```

Notice how each command nicely separates the logic, so anything you need to know about deleting a user can be found in the `DeleteUserCommand` class. I find this helps document my systems easier.

Think about it, and if it's suites what you need then cool.

Comment: If you define the arguments with a `params` keyword, you don't need to create the array explicitly when calling the method. The `args` paramter ist still a normal array that you can pass to the activator. `public ICommand Create<T>(params object[] args)`

Answer (score 0):

Well you just said it your self, it's called a Model, in fact what your describing is very close to what the `MVVM` Pattern is, which stands for: `Model-View-ViewModel`, the model being the the class which is simply a data template for your objects, the ViewModel where all the processing happens, and the view being the actual GUI.

You call the models, whatever they are... If it's a car, call it a car, if it's a house, call it a house, and keep your models in a separate library, it'll bring more structure to your code.